# Node.js unzip giving RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, unzip

I am seeing this error:

```
(node) warning: Recursive process.nextTick detected. This will break in the next  version of node. Please use setImmediate for recursive deferral.

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

My code is

```
  fs.readFile(req.files.module.path, function (err, data) {
    var newPath = __dirname + "/"+req.files.module.name;
    fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var readStream = fs.createReadStream(newPath);
      //var readStream = fs.createReadStream(data);
      var writeStream = fstream.Writer('./node_modules/');

      readStream
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
          .pipe(writeStream)
    });
  });
```

When I give a file upto 2MB(I tested for this size) code works fine and unzips it well. But when my zip file is around 6MB it gives above error.

I am using unzip node module to unzip.

Any pointer to mitigate this and handle gracefully or another way to unzip?

Comment: Why are you using fstream.Writer that too on a directory `./node_modules/`